# Show that $p_1p_2 \cdots p_t<4^n$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $n$ be an integer greater than $1$ and let $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_t$ be the primes not exceeding $n$. Show that $p_1p_2 \cdots p_t<4^n$.

We only need to consider $n$ to be of the form $n = p_i$ for every prime $p_i$. Therefore we have to prove that $$p_1p_2 \cdots p_i < 4^{p_i}.$$

Comment: This is used in the proof of Chebychev theorem and Betrand's postulate. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand%27s_postulate) and [that](https://www3.nd.edu/~dgalvin1/pdf/bertrand.pdf)

Comment: Observation: For up to $p_100$ it suffices to use $(2.62)^n$ in place of $4^n$.

Answer (score 3):

Every prime in the range $[n+1,2n]$ is a divisor of 
$$\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{2n\cdot(2n-1)\cdot\ldots(n+2)(n+1)}{n!} \tag{1}$$
and 
$$\binom{2n}{n} < \sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k} = 4^n \tag{2}$$
it follows that
$$ \prod_{p\in [n+1,2n]}p < 4^n \tag{3} $$
and by iterating the same argument over the intervals $\left[\frac{n}{2}+1,n\right],\left[\frac{n}{4}+1,\frac{n}{2}\right]$ and so on we get
$$ \prod_{p\in[1,2n]}p < 4^{2n}.\tag{4}$$

Comment: Yes,  problem has $<4^{p_i}$, not $<4^{2n}$, but of course $p_i < 2n$.

Comment: @MarkFischler: yes. I considered the product of the primes in the interval $[1,2n]$ and got that it is $<4^{2n}$, hence the product of the primes in the interval $[1,n]$ is less than $4^n$ as wanted.

Comment: Ah, I see now.  My earlier comment missed your point.  This proof is, IMHO, correct and should be given a check by the OP.  BTW, the bound can surely be tightened; does anybody know how far?  I would bet heavily it is always less than $3^n$ as well.

Comment: @MarkFischler: it can be tightened for sure. In the original Chebyshev's proof (https://integermiscellany.wordpress.com/2012/12/10/notes-on-the-chebyshev-theorem/) the constant $4$ is replaced by something close to $3.03$.